# Creating polygons from open ended line (riverine) feature

Tags: arcgis-pro, grouping

I have a dataset of rivers which I'd like to build into polygons of areas enclosed by rivers.
The rivers are continuous lines but there are open ends.

[image: River line features]

Is this possible? It's OK if the calculated boundary between the open aspects of the rivers is less precise, and it doesn't matter if the process causes gaps or forms a homogeneous polygon, either is OK.

Currently I'm drawing them by hand using the trace tool. I tried grouping by river/feature name but this wasn't successful. I also tried minimum bounding geometry, both as lines and converted to points, and if I select the points manually then it's fine, but I have no way to group them as again the name isn't helpful.

[image: Traced River Bounding Area]

Is this possible, or should I carry on tracing?

Comment: @BERA - It could be the start of the lines, yes. There are some that start/end along other lines, but if these were extended to another lines endpoint it wouldn't be too much of an issue. I'm afraid no knowledge of Python/ArcPy, but I'm willing to learn. Haven't coded in a long while and that was VB (so not sure it really counts hah)

Comment: @BERA - The one in the photo is yes, it's [DWER-031](https://catalogue.data.wa.gov.au/dataset/598ba78e-e486-4731-a8f4-235ce5661ead). from SA. I'm currently using all classes. No problem with QGIS for processing at all, i've got a little more experience with it than ArcMap anyway.

Comment: @BERA - Ah my bad, that's for the Arc/WMS stream. Here's the [national dataset as a file geodatabase](https://ecat.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/83130) or I've clipped a reference frame of the data I'm using directly [as a shapefile](https://gofile.io/d/yBKuIY)